# How to capture Ilogger.LogInformaiton in Azure portal for AppService Logfile implemented in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-log-analytics, ilogger

With the help of forum and research I am able to view the logfile for the errors occur in hosted ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. So when the error occurred, I captured that under `_logger.LogError("error)`.

But I also implemented `_logger.LogInformation("information")`. I do want to see this regardless of error.  After the implementation, I do not see the information logs.

Please see the below configurations:

`Program` file:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("https://*:5001").
        ConfigureLogging(logging => { logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(); })
        .ConfigureServices(services=>
        {
            services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.FileName = "my-azure-diagnostics-";
                options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
                options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
            });
        })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

`AppSettings.json`:

```
 "Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
     "Default": "Information",
     "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
 },
```

Comment: The Application Logging has to be set to Information to see all the logs including error.

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with `ASP.NET Core 6` we can configure the middleware directly in `Program.cs` file.

As mentioned earlier in my previous answer, I have used the same code to log traces in a file.

> ```cs
> builder.Services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options => 
> {
>     options.FileName = "LogTracestoFile";
>     options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
>     options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 3;
> });
> ```

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
builder.Services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileName = "LogTracestoFile";
    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 3;
});
```

My `.csproj` file:

```cs
 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices" Version="8.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

- To log traces in a file, the app uses the `Application Logging` settings from `App Service logs` .

[image]

*** Log stream:***

[image]

*****In file (`C:\home\LogFiles\Application`):*****

```cs
2023-12-05 09:50:46.141 +00:00 [Information] LogsILogger.Controllers.WeatherForecastController: Information Log in Log Stream
2023-12-05 09:50:46.175 +00:00 [Warning] LogsILogger.Controllers.WeatherForecastController: Warning Log
2023-12-05 09:50:46.186 +00:00 [Error] LogsILogger.Controllers.WeatherForecastController: Error Log
2023-12-05 09:50:46.189 +00:00 [Critical] LogsILogger.Controllers.WeatherForecastController: Critical Log
```

Comment: I am not able to capture the _logger.LogInformation("missing") in the file created under LogFiles\Application.  So what is it I am missing from my implmentation?   Do you think I have to update the LogStream settings in a dropdown to "Information" in order to captture "Information and errors?

Comment: Yes..change it to information.

Comment: Where does your log info reside.In controller?

Comment: Yes my log information reside in API controllers.  So bascially what you are saying if I go to kudu and open file from the logfile folder then I can see the information logs and error logs (if any , since I don't suppose to see the errors unless error occurd but information logs) as well as long as I have select the dropdown to Information from LogStream tool under Azure portal .

Comment: Yes.you can see the file gets updated each time when you run the app.All the traces and requests can be seen even if you don't have any error.

Comment: To be more clear ..check from your end by enabling information log level.

Comment: I will check and update.